# How do you retrieve "related" documents in Firestore? Nodejs Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

How do you retrieve "related" documents in Firestore? Nodejs Express.js

Answer (score 0):

If by related document you mean the "reference" datatype in Firestore, you can retrieve it from the Firestore using the get method, exactly like you would do when retrieving a single doc.

```js
myDoc.referencedDocument.get().then(result => {
    const data = result.data();
    // 'data' will contain the referenced document 
})
```